# HtmlAgilityPack : Descendants vs Xpath

Tags: html-agility-pack

Im working with the HtmlAgilityPack lib and having a few questions of understanding from my limited xpath knowledge. As the code sample below show, from immediate window, table is a htmlnode selected from DocumentNode. So with "/div" none is selected, "div" the one div child is selected, "//div" have selected all the divs in the document(so it did not find only its descendants. Therefor i have picked table.Descendants instead which give me the 5 divs i want.

I would like to know, is using xpath with the selectNodes method faster then just using linq (table.Descendants.Select(n=>n.attribute["class"] == "someclass")) ect.

And what is it i dont understand about xpath, why cant i select a specific elements descendants?

```
table.SelectNodes("/div");
null
table.SelectNodes("div")
{HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection}
   _items: Count = 1
   _parentnode: null
   Count: 1
   IsReadOnly: false
table.SelectNodes("//div")
{HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection}
   _items: Count = 84
   _parentnode: null
   Count: 84
   IsReadOnly: false
   table.Descendants("div").ToArray()
{HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode[5]}
   [0]: Name: "div"}
   [1]: Name: "div"}
   [2]: Name: "div"}
   [3]: Name: "div"}
   [4]: Name: "div"}
```

Comment: Here is a great resource for [XPATH queries](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).  Without seeing the HTML, I"m not sure what your trying to target but normally if you want to search for child elements of a specific node (e.g. your table nodes), I start my XPATH statement with "child::" or "./".

Comment: Yes - i had been on w3schools and reading - i had misunderstod it at the beginning - node/node1 do not mean find all node1 below node - so as you say with child:: - i was looking for the axis descendant:: .

Comment: here is some information on both xpath and linq that may be useful: http://beletsky.net/2010/09/crawling-web-sites-with-htmlagilitypack.html